# while(decision1 != 1 || decision1 != 2) why does this keep repeating even though decision is already 1 or 2

Tags: c++

This is the code. Why does it keep repeating even though decision is already 1 or 2?

```
    std::cout << "How many toppings do you want? (1/2): ";
    std::cin >> decision1;
        
    while(decision1 != 1 || decision1 != 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter either 1 or 2\n";
        std::cout << "How many toppings do you want? (1/2): ";
        std::cin >> decision1;
    }
```

Comment: the loop stops when `decision == 1 && decision == 2`. An `int` is always either not equal to `1` or not equal to `2` (or both)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When decision1 == 1, the condition `decision1 != 2` is true, and vice-versa.

Since decision1 cannot be both 1 and 2, `decision1 != 1 || decision1 != 2` is always true.

Answer (score 3):

Change the while loop condition to `decision1 != 1 && decision1 != 2`. This means 'do it while `decision1` is neither 1 or 2', and what you have now means 'do it while `decision1` is different than 1 or different than 2', and that's why it's repeating: the value will *always* be either different than 1 or different than 2.